# Add total sum for a column group ms sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hello I want to add column `Group` total summary added to my select query in SQL server 2008.

Is there any way to do this?

Expected output:

```
Group Number cost
A     5      $150
B     3      $100
A     7      $50
A     1      $20
A     total  $220
B     total  $100
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want--is it strictly necessary that your totals be a part of the results of the main select query?  What have you tried?

Comment: Does the rollup operator do what you need? Haven't used it for a while but might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not as a separate row; the only way I can think of to do that would be to run this as a function/stored proc and append that row to the end.  The other option is that you could include the SUM in each row; it's repetitive and not overly efficient but it's much quicker than changing into a SP.  If you're only working with Group A and Group B, the below works (again, very inefficiently).

```
SELECT
    [Group],
    Number,
    Cost,
    (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM someTable where [Group] = 'A'),
    (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM someTable where [Group] = 'B')
FROM
    someTable
```

Comment: If your Groups are dynamic then this gets much more complicated.  Still, very straightforward in a Function or Stored Proc though.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used sql-server, but in general:

```
SELECT [Group], SUM(cost) FROM someTable GROUP BY [Group];
```

Seems too simple. Are you asking a different question than I'm reading?